# Deserialize on the fly, or LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

Working with C# Visual Studio 2008, MVC1.

I'm creating an xml file by fetching one from a WebService and adding some nodes to it. Now I wanted to deserialize it to a class which is the model used to strongtyped the View.

First of all, I'm facing problems to achieve that without storing the xml in the filesystem cause I don't know how this serialize and deserialize work. I guess there's a way and it's a matter of time.

But, searching for the previous in the web I came accross LINQ to XML and now I doubt whether is better to use it.

The xml would be formed by some clients details, and basically I will use all of them.

Any hint?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a XElement to and from a `MemoryStream` (no need to save it to a file stream)

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
 document.Save(xw);
 xw.Flush();
```

Then if you reset the position back to 0 you can deserialize it using the DataContractSerializer.

```
 ms.Position = 0;
 DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Model));
 Model model = (model) serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

There are other options for how serialization works, so if this is not what you have, let me know what you are using and I will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot gbanfill, thing is that I'm getting an error from namespace but it does seem to be a step forward

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XElement)); 
FileStream FStream;
try 
{             
   FStream = new FileStream(doctorsPath, FileMode.Open);
  _Doctors = (XElement)xmls.Deserialize(FStream); FStream.Close(); 
   FStream = new FileStream(patientsPath, FileMode.Open); 
  _Patients = (XElement)xmls.Deserialize(FStream)
   FStream.Close(); 
   FStream = new FileStream(treatmentsPath, FileMode.Open);
  _Treatments = (XElement)xmls.Deserialize(FStream);
    FStream.Close(); 
} 
catch 

{ }
```

This will load all of the XML files into our XElement variables. The try – catch block is a form of exception handling that ensures that if one of the functions in the try block throws an exception, the program will jump to the catch section where nothing will happen. When working with files, especially reading files, it is a good idea to work with try – catch.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to XML is an excellent feature. You can always rely on that. You don't need to write or read or data from file. You can specify either string or stream to the XDocument

There are enough ways to load an XML element to the XDocument object. [See the appropriate Load functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx). Once you load the content, you can easily add/remove the elements and later you can save to disk if you want.